# how to get the column name list from a table in clojure

Tags: jdbc, clojure, metadata

I am using clojure.java.jdbc, and want to get the column name list from a table, but how should I do it in clojure? I found there is a function of result-set-read-column, and I guess I could use it, but I don't understand the function fully, could any one give an example?

Answer (score 2):

`result-set-read-column` [is for transforming values](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html), not what you want in this case.

This is the easiest way I can think of right now:

```
(defn column-names [db table]
  (let [rs (clojure.java.jdbc/query db (str "select * from " table " limit 1"))]
    (-> rs first keys)))
```

Comment: that only works if there are at least one row in the table. If the table is empty, then it doesn't work.

Comment: True. If you want to bypass clojure.java.jdbc you can call .getMetaData on a java ResultSet, or use a specific select statement for the database you're using (e.g. select table name in mysql).

Answer (score 2):

The `:as-arrays?` option of `query` returns the resultset as arrays, with the first array being the column names, the next arrays having the field information. This also works without results

```
(j/query db-spec
         ["select TOP 1 * from person"]
         :as-arrays? true)

[[:surname :first-name :age :gender]
 ["Doe" "John" 32 "male"]]

(j/query db-spec
         ["select TOP 0 * from person"]
         :as-arrays? true)

[[:surname :first-name :age :gender]]
```

If you want to process the resultset yourself, you can use `db-with-resultset` which takes a db-spec, a query vector, and a function to process the resultset. Be sure to realise everything in that function with a `doall` or `mapv` to prevent lazy processing and the resultset being closed before processing has finished.

```
(defn get-field-info
  [rs]
  (let [m (.getMetaData rs)]
    (into {} (mapv (fn [c] [(.getColumnName m c)
                            (.getColumnTypeName m c)])
                   (range 1 (inc (.getColumnCount m)))))))


(j/db-query-with-resultset db-spec
                           ["select TOP 0 * from person"]
                           get-field-info)

{"surname" "nvarchar","first-name" "nvarchar","age" "int","gender" "nvarchar"}
```

Be aware these options only return the metadata of the query resultset, not of the table itself !

```
(j/query db-spec
         ["select TOP 0 surname, first-name from person"]
         :as-arrays? true)

[[:surname :first-name]]
```

If you want to query the metadata of the database structure itself without using queries, you can use `with-database-metadata` and `metadata-query` from clojure.java.jdbc. The following will give all column names from the "person" table:

```
(j/with-db-metadata [m db-spec]
                    (->> (.getColumns m "mycatalog" nil "person" nil)
                         (j/metadata-query)
                         (map :column_name)))

["surname" "first-name" "age" "gender"]
```

The `with-db-metadata` binds the DataBaseMetaData of a db-spec to a var, so it only needs to be evaluated once, and the `metadata-query` processes the returns of a [Java DatabaseMetaData method call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCatalogs--) into a clojure data structure.